# wifi not working asus x550cc it is hard blocked

Tags: 14.04, wireless, asus

hello all i have Asus x550cc laptop with ath9k wifi card in which
I have a problem with Ubuntu 14.04. i can not enable wifi it shows wifi is disabled by WiFi switch
I tries 'rfkill list all' command it shows wireless Lan hard blocked yes.
I have no physical button in my comp for wifi all I know is alt+F2 for enabling disabling wifi pls help.

Comment: See my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/869987/ubuntu-16-04-no-wifi-after-suspend/897248#897248

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the module *asus_nb_wmi*  loaded? Check:

```
lsmod | grep asus
```

If so, try a temporary fix:

```
sudo modprobe -r asus_nb_wmi
sudo modprobe asus_nb_wmi wapf=1 
sudo rfkill unblock all
rfkill list all
```

Any improvement? If so, make the driver parameter permanent:

```
sudo -i
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb_wmi.conf
exit
```

If the parameter 1 is ineffective, we can also try 0 and 4.

Comment: hi thanks for your replay but sudo modprob doest work. the rfkill list all shows 0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
6: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
7: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: What is the error or message with modprobe? Did you confirm that asus_nb_wmi is loaded or no?

Comment: hii there i dont know how but when i put my pc on sleep for once my wifi start working normally... but for every boot i have to repeat this method every time ... is there any solution?.. and also when my wifi light turned on it can not work but when it is off my wifi start working??

Comment: Did you confirm that asus_nb_wmi is loaded or no?

Answer (score 1):

**To turn Wireless ON when your systeem starts up do the following:**

Open a Terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

***Enter the following line only if you don't have gksu installed.***

```
sudo apt-get install gksu -y
```

If you have GKSU (installed or already have) enter the following:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

The **rc.local** fill will open up, add the following line before the **exit 0**:

```
rfkill unblock wireless
```

Now enter the following line in a terminal:

```
sudo reboot
```

---

**To turn Bluetooth OFF when your systeem starts up do the following:**

Open a Terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

***Enter the following line only if you don't have gksu installed.***

```
sudo apt-get install gksu -y
```

If you have GKSU (installed or already have) enter the following:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

The **rc.local** fill will open up, add the following line before the **exit 0**:

```
rfkill block wireless
```

Now enter the following line in a terminal:

```
sudo reboot
```

---

To switch between ON or OFF you can use the <kbd>FN</kbd>+Wireless key on your keyboard.  This key is different for each system.
You can change **wireless** also for something else, like **bluetooth**.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed Linux Mint on my Asus X550C and I have found a way to enable wireless! I will write what I've done:

Terminal:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280
```

Bash answer: ...

```
...
Kernel driver in use: ath9k

lsmod | grep -e ath9k -e asus
```

Bash answer: ...
    ...
    asus_nb_wmi
    ...

Check if you find `asus_nb_wmi` in the output!

```
rfkill list all
```

See if "Hard blocked: yes".

Suspend the notebook by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> then resume it again and wireless will be enabled!