# wifi not working in asus x550cc on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, asus

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I am not able to connect through wi-fi.

I have tried out this [wifi not working asus x550cc it is hard blocked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474862/wifi-not-working-asus-x550cc-it-is-hard-blocked)

my `asus_nb_wmi` is loaded and

```
rfkill list all
```

Show this

```
2: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
3: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

edit :  I tried this too but in vain

```
sudo modprobe -r asus_nb_wmi
sudo modprobe asus_nb_wmi wapf=1 
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

Comment: I had a mysterious wifi problem on 14.04: [See this answer on AskUbuntu][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/a/607244/396480

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of surfing finally i found a solution.

I found [this](https://neurobin.org/projects/softwares/unix/MT7630E) driver built by ***Md Jahidul Hamid*** on github.

First of all download and extract the files.

Than give it execution permission by running

`chmod +x install test uninstall`

Now to install it run

`./install`

To test it without installing, run

`./test`

To uninstall, run

`./uninstall`

To install with dkms run

`sudo make dkms`

Hope this helps and a lot of thanks to all those who build this driver.

for more info visit this [blog](http://niteshsharma.me/2016/05/16/Asus-X550CC-wifi-issue-on-Ubuntu.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yours should work with `echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus_nm_wmi.conf`
Then you should be able to reboot and use your keyboard to enable wifi if it is still blocked

This should be fixed eventually as the code is in the asus_nb_wmi module in linux-next

```
.callback = dmi_matched,
    .ident = "ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. X550CC",
    .matches = {
        DMI_MATCH(DMI_SYS_VENDOR, "ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC."),
        DMI_MATCH(DMI_PRODUCT_NAME, "X550CC"),
    },
    .driver_data = &quirk_asus_wapf4,
```

Comment: I think i tried it too.... nd i want you to confirm the above code.... i think instead of asus_nm_wmi it should be asus_nb_wmi.... i apologise if i m wrong.... nd when i entered this command it shows error  sudo: tee/etc/modprobe.d/asus_nm_wmi.conf: command not found. Help me what to do nw

Comment: The command is `echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb_wmi.conf` I think you might have missed the space that should be between tee and /etc/modprobe.d/ as the file name after that can be anything as long as it ends with .conf  Instead of rebooting after entering that some of the time `sudo modprobe -r asus_nb_wmi` and `sudo modprobe asus_nb_wmi` works, it depends on a few things, the reboot always works