# Ubuntu 16.04 no wifi after suspend

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless, network-manager, suspend

I am able to connect to wifi before suspend, but afterwards no networks are listed. Other solutions say to use:

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service                
or
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Both of these resets the wifi connection as expected before a suspend, but after they don't work.

I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS on a Dell Venue Pro 7130.

Any solutions?

Comment: Did you try this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/748113/wifi-still-sleeping-when-resume/748130#748130

Comment: Yes. Just tried it. It didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a bug that's been happening from 16.04 and in 16.10 in many devices. My solution has been to turn the computer off and then back on. I know this sucks, but you can help by reporting the bug in ubuntu website.

Comment: I dont know if your answer is accurate, but this is my personal experience too.

Comment: where is the bug report?

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on an HP Pavilion Sleekbook 14-b120dx

```
product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
driver=ath9k driverversion=4.8.0-41-generic
```

It seems like a lot of people have similar problems, but none of the solutions I found work.  This is what I came up with and it seems to be working.

For me the issue was the wifi worked when first booted, but then would stop working after waking the computer up from being suspended.

The main difference from what I was having from some other people is running `rfkill list all` showed `Hard blocked: yes`

So my solution is to remove the wifi driver before suspending the system and adding it back afterwards and then rebooting the network-manager.

You can test out my solution and see if it works for you before making ir permanent below:

```
modprobe -r ath9k
```

suspend then wake up the computer, then run:

```
modprobe ath9k
service network-manager restart
```

If that works for you, you can make it permanent by adding a file to `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` or `/etc/pm/sleep.d/`

`sudo gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/wifi`

paste in this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
    suspend)
        modprobe -r ath9k
        ;;
    resume) 
        modprobe ath9k
        service network-manager restart
        ;;
esac
```

save and close the file, then run `sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/wifi`

You should be all set

Comment: `networ-manager` should probably be `network-manager`